# ES6 export default imports into default object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've recently upgraded to babel 6.0 and I've run into issues with exporting objects as default. It seems that whenever I export an object using `export default` and then `import` the object it gets placed under a `default` object.

For example:

```
let a = {};

a.b = 'c';

export default a;
```

Will import as the following:

```
import a from './a';

a.b       // undefined
a.default // { b: 'c' }
```

This worked properly under babel 5.0. I'm also using `babel-loader` with webpack.

`babel-loader` config:

```
{
  test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a bug (of either babel or your loader)

Comment: what does your babel config look like?

Comment: @max I added my babel-loader config.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with your sample. There was a change in behavior between 5.x and 6.x, but this doesn't demonstrate it. Are you sure the sample code you've given is the issue?

Comment: Take a look at this similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default, seems this is the intended behavior.

Comment: @LarryLee post this as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [Babel 6 changes how it exports default](/q/33505992/4642212), as per comments and answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, as Larry Lee pointed out, this can probably be considered a duplicate of this question.

[Babel 6 changes how it exports default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default?lq=1)