# Webpack umd library return Object.default

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, umd

I'm writing a lib with webpack with these settings:

```
output: {
    path: path.join('build'),
    filename: 'my_lib.js',
    library: 'MyLib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
```

MyLib:

```
export default function() {
  console.log('MyLib');
}
```

The problem is, when I try to load the build/my_lib.js in a browser, the only way to access MyLib is through MyLib.default...

Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should set `libraryExport`  to `default`;

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport

Answer (score 8):

the key is to use `libraryExport: "default"` like this:

```js
  module.exports = {
    entry: ...,
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "/dist/",
      filename: "Template.js",
      library: "Template",
      libraryTarget: "umd",
      libraryExport: "default",
      globalObject: "this",
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

**If you are asking about any idea of why?**

If you are using Babel to enable ES6 features then you are probably facing one of the changes between Babel5 and Babel6.

With Babel5 your code is transpiled to this:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
});

exports['default'] = function () {
  console.log('MyLib');
};

module.exports = exports['default'];
```

But with Babel6 you get:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports.default = function () {
  console.log('MyLib');
};
```

Do you spot the difference?

```
module.exports = exports['default'];
```

This line was [killed](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2212) in Babel6. Here it was decided:

> To always export a default to `exports.default`

**If you are asking about any idea to workaround it?**

You can add this line yourself or use some kind of [babel plugin that adds it for you](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports).

```
const myLib = function () {
  console.log('MyLib');
};

export default myLib;

module.exports = myLib;
```

Comment: Please consider voting for feature request here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3929 ;)