# How to bundle module without dependencies for publishing npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

Recently, I developed a React component and want to publish it.

In this package,

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14.6",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
  "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3"
}
```

When I build the package by `webpack` command, I will get a bundle containing `react, react-dom and react-timer-mixin`. 
It seems wrong for this practice...

Thus, my question is how to build package without dependencies for publishing.

*I think the chuck-vendor method to separate main bundle and dependencies is for multiple bundle file. But my requirement is for building the lib.

Comment: I have added some content to reply you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I agree, your case is actually a bit different. I removed my remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are building a library, you need to register these dependencies as [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

To summarise, just add the `externals` property in your webpack config and set it to an array containing the names (string) of the modules to exclude.

A more complex case could require you to specify how should be imported your dependencies in function of the import system. You can achieve this using an object.

[Here is the official example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/externals):

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    externals: [
        "add",
        {
            "subtract": {
                root: "subtract",
                commonjs2: "./subtract",
                commonjs: ["./math", "subtract"],
                amd: "subtract"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[See here for more information about library and externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

If you are using ES 2015 and babel 6, you may also encounter an issue with the export of the library being a module object instead of what you want (e.g. your component). [Have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678869/make-webpacks-library-output-compatible-with-babel6) to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use `peerDependencies` instead. Then you can build without webpack for publishing. If you use ES6, all you need is a babel transpilation step.

Something like this is often enough

```
babel ./src -d ./lib
```

Peer dependencies will let npm know the project using your package should have those dependencies installed.