# Exporting a class with Webpack and Babel not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I have a very simple setup with Webpack and Babel for a small library.

Before, I had the following architecture to generate a ES5 version of the library:

```
module.exports.lib = (function () {
    /* private part of library here */

    return {
        ... /* public part of library here */
    }
})();
```

Everything is working fine this way, and I even had some ES6 features such as arrow functions inside my library and everything worked. However, I decided to change my approach to a ES6 class, this way:

```
export default class Library {

}
```

And now, when I try to do:

```
var library = new Library();
```

I get that Library was not defined. Even just evaluating `Library` returns undefined.

So what I did was turn the file that uses the library into an ES6 file that does `import Library from 'libraryfile.js'` and it worked again.

However, I'd really like my output library to still be usable from regular ES5 with a `<script>` tag just like before. Is this possible?

Here's my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pentagine: "./lib/pentagine.js",
    demos: ["./demos/helicopter_game/PlayState.js"]
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./build/[name].js",
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: *"However, I'd really like my output library to still be valid ES5. Is this possible?"* Babel already does that...

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, it is valid ES5, but I want I meant is that I want it to be usable by regular ES5 code with a normal script tag. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33678869/218196

Comment: It helped as I learnt quite a lot but it doesn't seem to be the same issue as using the `add-module-exports` plugin didn't fix the problem.

Comment: did you solve this problem I am also facing the same error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Default exports are stored in the `default` property of the module. If you want to make your library accessible without users having to know that, you can change your webpack entry file to

```
module.exports = require('./libraryfile').default;
```

Also, make sure you have `library: 'YourLibraryName'` in your webpack config as per webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library.

Comment: Sounds fair, so I created an `entry.js` which only code is `module.exports = require('./pentagine.js').default;`. I changed the entry file in webpack to `entry.js` but I still get undefined.

Comment: Does `pentagine.js` have a default export?

Comment: Yes it has, `export default class Pentagine` is what it is. (you can see it here https://github.com/davidgomes/pentagine.js/tree/es6-version)

Comment: I guess you also need `library: 'YourLibraryName'` in your webpack config. http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library

Comment: `library: 'YourLibraryName'` is removed in webpack 4

Answer (score 4):

Webpack has changed a lot, now you can get the same results as the Felix Kling answer but with webpack config. You should add the **libraryExport** key in the output config and set it to **"default"**. That would set your main class as the root content of your library. Here are the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport).

Your webpack config should be like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pentagine: "./lib/pentagine.js",
    demos: ["./demos/helicopter_game/PlayState.js"]
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./build/[name].js",
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default' //<-- New line
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As Matias points out, webpack must be configured to export the default in order to avoid your client code doing `const MyLibrary = require('MyLibrary').default`

In 2021, using webpack 5, the correct config is:

```
module.exports = {
    
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        library: {
            name: 'MyLibrary',
            type: 'umd',
            export: 'default' //<--- important
        },
    },

    // specify entry and other configs per usual..
}
```

ref: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport