# How to expose an es6 module globally

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, global-variables, webpack

I need to write a module that will be available on the window global.
I'm using es6 to create the module and every single class I define has it's own file.
I'm using webpack to babelify and bundle these classes.
The entry point of my module is also the file containing the global to be exposed.

**I've tried every method to make this possibe, icluding:**

- expose-loader
- import-loader
- expoert-loader
- output: library
- black-magic :(

**Example of code I've tried:**

I want to get: window.MyMod

```
// mymod.js
export class MyMod {
    constructor(aaa) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.aaa;
    }
}
```

```
// webpack.config
var entries = [
    './src/mymod.js'
];
module.exports = {
    ...,
    module: {
      loaders: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('./src/mymod.js'),
                loader: 'expose?MyMod'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
    ]
}
```

This only gets me an object MyMod on the window that contains MyMod as a constructor.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: not a config solution but can't you just have an index file for your module that does `import lib from './lib'; window.lib = lib`

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but you are saying: *I'm using webpack to babelify and bundle these classes...*  and *...This only gets me an object MyMod on the window that contains MyMod as a constructor.*  Isn't that exactly what bable is doing when compiling ES6 ? Classes will be compiled to constructor functions, because in ES5 classes do not exist.

Comment: Maybe I should somehow wrap the class in an anonymous self invoking function returning MyMod?

Comment: Did you try using the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)?

Answer (score 5):

You should combine `export default class Foo` with the [`library`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library) and [`libraryTarget`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) settings in Webpack's config. Something like:

```
// src/Foo.js
export default class Foo { ... }

// webpack.config.json
{
  "output": {
    "library": "Foo",
    "libraryTarget": "var"
  }
}
```

You should be able to use the library as `window.Foo` once the bundle has been loaded.

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work. Resulted in an empty window.Foo object

Comment: @bldoron did you set the `entry` in your config as well? I think that may be necessary to get a reliable global var.

Answer (score 4):

This is basically the same issue as [Exporting a class with Webpack and Babel not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37912857/218196) , except that you have a named export instead of a default export. Your entry file should be

```
import {MyMod} from './mymod';
module.exports = MyMod;
```

or

```
module.exports = require('./mymod').MyMod;
```

---

If you don't want to do any of these and keep `'./src/mymod.js'` as entry file, use a CommonJS export instead of an ES6 export in that file:

```
// mymod.js
exports.MyMod = class MyMod {
    constructor(aaa) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.aaa;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to be more specific, otherwise it's not possible to help you.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. Your first solution is impossible, because i'm not importing the file anywhere, I need it to be built.  
The second one, I did try, but this: `require.resolve('./src/mymod.js')` and this `require.resolve('./src/mymod.js').MyMod` resulted in the same window.MyMod.MyMod.

Comment: *"Your first solution is impossible, because i'm not importing the file anywhere,"* I said you have to create a *new entry file* with that content, instead of using `./src/mymod.js` as entry file. I.e.  create a file `./src/entry.js` with the content from my answer and configure webpack to use that: `var entries = [ './src/entry.js'];`

Comment: I've been trying to avoid that, it sounds like a hack. I think I'll do what jquery did and somehow wrap the class in an anonymous self invoking function returning MyMod. I'll report back with this try- though it also is a hack.

Comment: Well, you are trying to make ES6 modules work together with a tool that is built for CommonJS modules. If you don't want use any of the suggestions and keep `./src/mymod.js` as entry file then you should use a CommonJS module definition instead of ES6: `exports.MyMod = class MyMod {};`. Implementing a wrapper like jQuery does is completely unnecessary because that's exactly what webpack does for you.

Comment: What finally worked was: module.exports = class MyMod {...}
and exposing it as I did: 
test: require.resolve('./src/mymod.js'),
loader: 'expose?MyMod'

Comment: @bidoron can you write an answer that sums up how to do this? All I get is an empty global var.