# How to export a ES6 class with Webpack and Babel to AMD

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to write a class in ES6 and transpile it into a library as an AMD module with Babel (and bundle with jQuery in the same file) so people can use it like this:

```
<script src="Foo.js"></script>
<script>
    var dummy = new Foo();
</script>
```

I followed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912857/exporting-a-class-with-webpack-and-babel-not-working) and arrange my folder like this:

```
-dist
-js
  |--Foo.js
  |--main.js
-lib
  |--jquery.js
-node_modules
-webpack.config.js
-.babelrc
-.eslintrc
-package.json
```

and `Foo.js`:

```
import $ from '../lib.jquery.js';

export default class Foo {
    constructor(){
        /* jQuery stuff */
    }
}
```

and `main.js`:

```
module.exports = require('./Foo.js').default;
```

and `webpack.config.js`:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    name: "bundle-js",
    entry: {
        Foo: [
            // configuration for babel6
            'babel-polyfill',
            './js/main.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  // ./build
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        library: 'Foo',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

and `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"],
    "presets": ["react", "es2015","stage-0"]
}
```

And I kept getting this error:

```
js/main.js: Property object of MemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Expression"] but instead got null
```

Can somebody please help me and tell me what went wrong so I can fix it? AMD is more of my preference, so if someone has a solution that uses CommonJS and does the same thing, I'm open to it.

Edit: To avoid distraction, this problem has nothing to do with Webpack, as I used the command `babel --presets es2015 --plugins transform-es2015-modules-amd js/main.js -o dist/Foo.bundle.js` and still have the same error.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but why are you using webpack with AMD? Webpack is a *bundler*, and AMD is for async script loading... seems to me with your `.babelrc` that you could just skip webpack?

Comment: Since `Class` is ES6 syntax, so I want to transpile it to ES5 with babel so most browser can still support it. I tried transpiling without using Webpacj but with the command `babel --presets es2015 --plugins transform-es2015-modules-amd js/main.js -o dist/Foo.bundle.js` but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Throwing random build tools at errors you don't understand won't fix them. So lets start at the beginning: are you including `require.js` in a script tag on your page? What does your load order look like? Side note: if you have a `.babelrc` why are you manually passing CLI parameters? Last but not least, if you are intent on releasing this as a *library* you should arguably use UMD for maximum ease of use.

Comment: @JaredSmith The error happens when I try to run `npm run webpack`. `RequireJS` is also already installed.

Comment: Again, **why are you using webpack!?!?** Nothing about any of this makes any sense at all. You say its a library but your bundling jquery instead of listing it as a dep in `package.json`, trying to bundle the whole thing with webpack, presenting it as an AMD even though CJS is far more popular (and you can support both with UMD), etc. etc. May I respectfully suggest that if you ever expect this to get used you need to take a long hard look at how popular existing libraries actually handle these things.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for your comment. I'm already considering alternative options other than webpack. I only used it because I was sorta of hyped about Webpack 2.0, but writing the cofig is still very painful for me. I'm already using Babel to test my code now. Like I said, I got the same error even using an `babel`command, so the problem should have something to do with `babel` instead of Webpack. I only included jQuery as an example, I actually wrote something else into the lib folder, I thought replacing it with jQuery in the question avoids distraction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135184/discussion-between-kevlai22-and-jared-smith).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the AMD transformer plugin, something you are trying to include uses `require` which it can't handle. See [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4072) github issue for details. Try the UMD plugin instead, especially since you say you want to release this as a library.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is wrong in yours but my way is below:

install jquery via npm

```
npm i jquery;
```

then configure webpack.conf

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
    },
...
// for jquery plugins
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   'jQuery': 'jquery',
   'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
   'window.$': 'jquery',
}),

...
```

and import jquery

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with jQuery, I tried doing the same thing without the `import $ from '../lib.jquery.js';` statement and I still have the same error.