# React router dynamic routes not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I’m trying to get react router dynamic routing to work by following this example: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps

Here’s my setup:

`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: './js/app.js',
  output: {
    path: '../public',
    filename: 'test-app.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: [
            'es2015',
            'react'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

`./js/app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

const history = useBasename(createHistory)({
  basename: '/'
});

const rootRoute = {
  component: 'div',
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: require('./components/App')
  }]
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history} routes={rootRoute} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`./components/App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

console.log('testing');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('App');
    return (
        <div>
          App!
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="public/test-app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the server, I see *Hello* displayed from `index.html`, I also see `console.log('testing')` from `App.js`, but the actual `App.js` component does not render. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
If I change `./components/App.js` to ES5 syntax below, it works! Why is that? Does react router's `component: require('./components/App')` not work with ES6?

```
var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        App!
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you are using Babel 6, where they [changed](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2212) commonjs `require` syntax.

Now, you need to add the `default`:

```
component: require('./components/App').default
```

I had the same problem, finally found how to make it work.

Comment: There is also a [similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default) with some answers.