# create-react-app, code splitting and jest

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux

I'm developing an application using create-react-app and I'm trying to split my code into modules implementing the way described in the react-router huge-apps example.
Everything works well except the unit tests : I get this error while running the jest tests for the route components :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined
```

A route component looks like this :

```
export class IntroPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        ...
    }
};

module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)(IntroPage);
```

and a test :

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {IntroPage} from '../IntroPage';

it('should render without crashing', () => {
    shallow(
        <IntroPage {...props}/> // IntroPage is undefined
    )
});
```

How do I have to export/import my components to be able to test them properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using both ES6 export syntax and CommonJS module.exports in one file? This is not supported.

Comment: CommonJS syntax is supported for compatibility but you shouldn't use it in any new code. Mixing them is wrong semantically because they have conflicting meanings.

Comment: I know but if I export the component like I use to do in es6 (export default), it doesn't work.

Comment: I have to say my route definition looks like this :
    export default {
        childRoutes: [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: require('./components/app/App')
            },
            {
                path: '*',
                onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/')
            }
        ]
    };

Comment: This is the way exposed in the react-router example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with this post : [React router dynamic routes not rendering component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847789/react-router-dynamic-routes-not-rendering-component)

I just had to add 'default' to the require statements when exporting with es6 module.

Answer (score 1):

If you transpile in Babel:

```
export class IntroPage extends React.Component {
   ...
}
```

You will notice that Babel will move that to the `exports` variable.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
... more good stuff
...
var IntroPage = exports.IntroPage = function (_React$Component) {
```

So you can console.log these:

```
console.log(exports);
console.log(module.exports);
console.log(module);
```

and check `exports` variable and `module` object.
In here `module.exports` should be the same as `exports`.

If you type:

```
 module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)(IntroPage);
```

at the end of your component file, you are overwriting the `module.exports` with the new value.

This is the core of the problem.

#### The solution?

I think you already found one, but the best would be not to mix commonJS with ES6 export, since ES6 export will be transpiled to commonJS syntax.

---

Check also "[What is export default in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)"

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was not a good idea to mix syntaxes but since it was the way it was done in the react-router example, I thought it was the good one.

> but the best would be not to mix commonJS with ES6 exports

What do you mean? I'm still mixing syntaxes with the solution I found? I thought I didn't.

Comment: BTW, react-router is not a superior product. It is heavy when you include it on a page and you cannot find it mentioned in the default react project documentation by Facebook, and more if you search for `react router alternative` you will find more reasons not to use it in the future.

Comment: Sure but I'm making my way step by step :)