# Import statement and Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, fbjs

I'm defining two constants using `keyMirror` from Facebook's `fbjs`.

```
// file1.js
import keyMirror from 'fbjs/lib/keyMirror'
export default keyMirror({
    CONST1: null,
    CONST2: null,
})
```

then import them in `file2.js`:

```
// file2.js
import { CONST1, CONST2 } from './file1'
console.log(CONST1) // undefined
```

their values can't be resolved. If I change `file2.js` like so:

```
// file2.js
import constants from './file1'
console.log(constants.CONST1) // CONST1
```

it works fine. What's wrong with it? I'm using Babel 6 with `babel-preset-es2015` to run the scripts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your imports do not match, if you export a `default` export, you must import a `default`. If you want to import using `named` exports, then you need to export using `named` exports.

For

```
import { CONST1, CONST2 } from './file1'
```

to work, you'd need

```
export let {CONST1, CONST2} = keyMirror({
    CONST1: null,
    CONST2: null,
});
```

The `{ CONST1, CONST2 }` after `import` in ES6 module syntax is unrelated to destructuring, so you should not think of it as pulling properties off of the default export. Instead, think of it as a list of names to import from the module.

Your solution would potentially have worked with Babel 5, but it was still invalid, even then. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default/33506169#33506169) for more of an explanation of that.

Each ES6 module exports a set of exports, with `default` being special-cased for simplicity.

```
import constants from './file1';
```

is short for

```
import {default as constants} from './file1';
```

and

```
export default keyMirror({
    CONST1: null,
    CONST2: null,
})
```

is essentially short for

```
var temp = keyMirror({
    CONST1: null,
    CONST2: null,
});
export {temp as default};
```

Comment: Hm, don't we have a duplicate for this?

Comment: It is totally possible.

Comment: While your explanation seems logical, the example given above is very much similar to NuclearJS shopping cart example. Have a look at [`actionTypes.js`](https://github.com/optimizely/nuclear-js/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/actionTypes.js) where constants are defined and [`productStore.js`](https://github.com/optimizely/nuclear-js/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/stores/ProductStore.js) where they're imported using the former syntax in my question. It works fine using Webpack, but with Babel, it gives the error mentioned.

Comment: Great, thanks for the examples. That is indeed invalid, but it worked in the past because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default/33506169#33506169

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems to be the case. Please update your answer with that link and a bit of explanation so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: I've been banging my head for hours, I was using `import {...}` instead of `import ...`  
Thanks !