# Why is webpack code splitting not working for me?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, react-router, code-splitting

I'm using require.ensure to create split points at **react-router** paths. However, my build directory still only has `app.js` in addition to the `vendor.js`. I was expecting a separate js file for each path I used `require.ensure`.

I used `require.ensure` at each path like this:

```
<Route path= 'auth' getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
  require.ensure([], (require) => {
    callback(null, require('containers/Authenticate/AuthenticateContainer.js').default)
  }, 'auth')
}}/>
```

my web pack config output for build looks like this:

```
output: {
  path: PATHS.build,
  filename: '/[name].[chunkhash].js',
  chunkFilename: '/[chunkhash].js'
}
```

Here are the gists of my [route file](https://gist.github.com/jasan-s/8c17d5bd7bdf63de1c82f21221827a08) and my [webpack config file](https://gist.github.com/jasan-s/1514be3b792cf75a5724292b1fa98951) in their entirety.

**UPDATE:**   I figured out what I was doing wrong. My project structure for containers is like so:

```
-app
 -containers
   -containerA.
     -containerA.js
   -containerB
     -containerB.js
   -containerC
     -containerC.js
   -index.js
```

The issue: I was still exporting the containers I was requiring in routes file like so: export containerB from './containerB/containerB'
Removing the export in the index.js and requiring straight from the containerB.js did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure takes an argument array of modules you want to require. You need to supply the array with the module names you wish to dynamically load.  In your case, provide 'containers/Authenticate/AuthenticateContainer.js' to ensure like this:

```
require.ensure(['containers/Authenticate/AuthenticateContainer.js'], (require) => {
      callback(null, require('containers/Authenticate/AuthenticateContainer.js').default)
    }, 'auth');
```

Comment: adding that makes no difference to the build directory.

Comment: is there something in the webpack config i need to include for it to work.

Comment: If you copied verbatim I missed a single quote at the end. No there shouldnt be anything else you need to configure.

Comment: @jasan please let us know what happened

Comment: @MitchKarajohn I have not yet solved this problem. One option I do have is to upgrade to webpack 2.0 and use the new system.imports but  that would also require me to make lot of other changes in my config. Thus i'm holding off on that.

Comment: Ill spin up a sandbox today to see whats up.  If you have the time commit your code to github and I can take a look.

Comment: @cgatian I have already linked the config and routes files. Are they not enough?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on one of my project : we used Systemjs and decided to switch to Webpack, so it broke our System.import. We fix it by replacing :

```
System.import(modulePath)
  .then(module => {
    // Do things
  })
```

With :

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(require(modulePath));
}).then((module) => { 
  // Do things 
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Richard I'm not using Webpack 2.0. I am using their latest stable version.

Comment: Isn't system import only for webpack 2.0 , require.ensure is used in earlier version of webpack.

Comment: Yes it is, and it broke our app. So we replace it with an equivalent using promises (the second code in my comment)

Comment: Richard Can you post a gist with an example using it with react router routes. Its unclear.

Answer (score 0):

i am using webpack 1.13.1 and here is my config

```
output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        publicPath:"/"
    },
```

here is the code for get component

```
const lazyLoadSomeComponent = () => {
  return {
      getComponent: (location, callback)=> {
        require.ensure([], require => {
          callback(null, require("./componentpath")["default"]);
        }, 'componentName');
      }
    }
};
```

Then in route

```
<Route path="somepath" {...lazyLoadSomeComponent()} />
```

**But Whats going here ?**

- First we create a function that will return the get component Method for us.
- Second we call that function in route and execute it so we get the get  component Method there , this will make routes easy to read
- Last in webpack specify the public path so "/" here resolves from root of your server, you can also specify your domain here

For Further Enhancement we can load multiple component at once using below method

```
const LazyComponents = (pageName) => {
  return {
      getComponent: (location, callback)=> {
        require.ensure([], require => {
          switch(pageName){
            case 'Component1':
            callback(null, require("./components/component1")["default"]);
            break;
            case 'Component2' :
                callback(null, require( "./components/component2" )["default"]);
                    break ;

        }, "CombinedComponents");
      }
    }
};
```

Then in Routes

```
<Route path="somepath" {...LazyComponents('Component1')} />
```