# cannot import local dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to write a local npm module in ES6, i'm using babel, npm... I have no error when i'm running npm install, but when i'm trying to call the module i have this error :

> Cannot find module './lib/daihinmin'

I have tried almost everything in my require :

```
var daihinmin=require('./lib/daihinmin');
var daihinmin=require('daihinmin');
var daihinmin=require('daihinmin.js');
```

None of this works and i don't see why :(

This is my module package.json :

```
{
  "name": "daihinmin",
  "main": "./lib/daihimin.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "babel --presets es2015 -d lib/ src/",
    "prepublish": "npm run compile"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0"
  }
}
```

And this is my app package.json :

```
{
  "name": "MrPresident",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "daihinmin": "./lib/daihinmin"
  }
}
```

[screenshot of my application tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puoYH.png)

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Are you exporting in `daihinmin.js`?

Comment: It was a typo in my export (a noob mistake) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

It's fixed thanks to :

[Babel 6 changes how it exports default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default)

Just a typo in my export.

```
export default class Daihimin {
    helloWorld() {
        console.log("helloWorld");
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
export default class Daihinmin {
    helloWorld() {
        console.log("helloWorld");
    }
}
```

Thank you!

But now i've got an other error :

*daihinmin.helloWorld is not a function*

```
var daihinmin=require('daihinmin');
daihinmin.helloWorld();
```

And again i can't understand why :(

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Don't ask another question in your answer, just make a new question. (Although, use the search feature first, since the question you're asking here is a duplicate).