# babel relay plugin - es6 configuration

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, relayjs

I am doing a test app that is all es6 ... and i hit a bump when using this plugin ... the docs say to use this to configure the plugin and it works:

```
var getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
var schemaData = require('../data/schema.json').data;
module.exports = getBabelRelayPlugin(schemaData, {
  abortOnError: true
});
```

can anyone tell me why this syntax does not work?

```
"use strict";

import getBabelRelayPlugin from 'babel-relay-plugin';
import schemaData from '../data/schema.json';

export default getBabelRelayPlugin(schemaData.data, {
  abortOnError: true
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, to import your plugin using the standard CommonJS `require` you can write:

```
var myBabelRelayPlugin = require('./myBabelRelayPlugin.js');
```

But in the ES6 case **if your module was transpiled by Babel 6**, you have to add `.default` at the end:

```
var myBabelRelayPlugin = require('./myBabelRelayPlugin.js').default;
```

Most probably Babel does not try to add `.default` when loading plugins, so it cannot load ES6 version of your plugin correctly.

Comment: thanks dened for your input ... i asked if ur answer is correct on the github forum and will mark it as the right answer when i get a feedback from them :)

Comment: This is really a Babel question, not a Relay question. Mark as correct if it works?

Comment: There's more info on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default