# Why does switching to import from require fix a runtime error?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack, ES6, and Babel for a project. A module had a require statement like so:

`var ajaxGetJSON = require("../utils/ajaxGetJSON");`

The bundle compiled fine but threw a runtime error that

`Uncaught TypeError: ajaxGetJSON is not a function`

Here is an examination of the object provided by webpack to my module:

[image]

When I change the require to an `import ajaxGetJSON from "../utils/ajaxGetJSON";` the runtime error does not occur and the inspected object that should be the function `ajaxGetJSON` works properly.

The ajax module uses `export default myObject`.

Why does switching to an import fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the debugger tooltip, `require()` yields an ES6 module object (which is what babel transpiles modules to) that is not a function but has the function as its `.default` property.

`ajaxGetJSON` is a *default export* of that module, and you should import it as such. If you are using ES6 modules, you should not use `require` at all.

Comment: I'm coming to that realization now; we use require mostly when we need to use rewire to mock dependencies in our test suite. Good rule to follow. If we want to fix this for some reason, we would need to `let foo = require("foo").default` then?

Comment: Yes, that would work (until babel changes its module format - which is unlikely but [has happened before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33505992/1048572)).