# is it possible to require transpiled to es5 Node.js module?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing a very simple Node.js module in es6

```
export default 'abc';
```

and I want to be able to use it in another Node.js script after transpiling to ES5:

```
var helper = require('./dist/helper.js');
console.log(helper)
```

for some reason - after transpilation I am getting

"{}" log

I want it to say "abc"...

Where am I wrong?

My webpack.conf:

```
    var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');


    module.exports = {
        entry:[
            './es6/helper.js'
        ],
        target: 'node',
        output:{
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: './dist/helper.js'
        },
        debug:'true',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        module: {

            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    include: path.join(__dirname, 'es6'),
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: "./es6"
        }  
    }
```

Comment: You might need to use the default export: `var helper = require('./dist/helper.js').default;` - [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default)

Comment: yes, i have tried this - the log is "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 
to add `libraryTarget:'commonjs2',`
in the webpack.conf:

```
    var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');


    module.exports = {
        entry:[
            './es6/helper.js'
        ],
        target: 'node',
        output:{
            libraryTarget:'commonjs2',
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: './dist/helper.js'
        },
        debug:'true',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        module: {

            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    include: path.join(__dirname, 'es6'),
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: "./es6"
        }  
    }
```