# How to use babel in combination with coffee-script in my mocha tests

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

I like to write my unit test with coffee-script and use mochajs as a framework.
I use following settings to configure mocha to use coffee-script.

```
node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ./tests/ --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --reporter spec
```

Unfortunately registering two compilers doesn't work.

```
node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ./tests/ --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register, js:babel-core/register --reporter spec
```

assuming that js-files will be transpiled with babel and coffee-files will be handled with coffee-script. But does not seam to work.

My production code (which I want to test) is written in es6 and transpiled with babel in webpack.

How would I set up mocha so that the production code will be transpiled from es6 and can be used in my coffee-script tests?

**//EDIT**

To extend the question and explain it in detail I just added a sample

I have a code file in JS es6

```
//hello.js
const hello = (msg) =>{
  return msg;

}

export default hello;
```

my coffee script test looks like this

```
#test1.coffee

should = require "should"

hello = require "./hello"

describe "Given I have an es6 module",->
  it "it should be possible to test it with mocha and coffeescript",->
    a = hello
    should.exist a
  it "it should also print out the given message",->
    msg = hello "world"
    msg.should.eql "world
```

my .babelrc looks like this

```
//.babelrc
{
  "presets":["es2015"],
   "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

My test output looks like this.

```
Given I have an es6 module
    ✓ it should be possible to test it with mocha and coffeescript
    1) it should also print out the given message


  1 passing (11ms)
  1 failing

  1) Given I have an es6 module it should also print out the given message:
     TypeError: hello is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (test1.coffee:10:11)
```

It looks like the hello.js module is imported (required) but will not be transformed into a commonjs module.

when I console.log hello -> I get `{ default: [Function: hello] }`

my tests are executed with `npm test test1.coffee`

And my current call from packages.json is:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require babel-polyfill --require coffee-script/register  --reporter spec --recursive"
  },
```

Any advice how to setup mocha to compile es6 on-the-fly and run the coffeescript tests would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is really not descriptive enough.  Do you have error output, or can you more clearly explain the result?

Comment: I explained it in detail above

Comment: This is by design. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default for explanation.

Comment: Maybe this should be marked as a dupe of the above referenced question.