# Possible strange behaviour with ES6 deconstruction syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been using the deconstruction syntax `{ ...variable }` for quite awhile now, but I've never really had a problem with it until today, while most of my use cases still work as expected this one is a bit confusing to myself.

I have a JS file that generates an object and exports it, ex:

```
var exports = {} 
...
export default exports;
```

There are not any nested objects and by the end of the file it's a simple KVP.

When trying to import from this file any objects I attempt to get through deconstruction are undefined. For example:

```
import { Foo, Bar } from './my-object';
Foo.bar(); // Cannot read property bar of undefined
```

However, if I break it apart farther like so, everything is fine:

```
import MyObject from './my-object';
const { Foo, Bar } = MyObject;
Foo.bar(); // Works!
```

I've tried changing `exports` to a different variable name as I thought maybe, just maybe it was a confliction with module.exports, but that wasn't the problem.

In the past whenever I exported an object it was simple:

```
 export default { ... }
```

I'm really confused on what the issue could be this time around as the result of `console.log(exports)` is the same thing:

```
{ Foo: foo, Bar: bar }
```

Where `bar()` is a function variable of `foo`

I should also add that trying to hack this to have the proper results doesn't work either, for example:

```
export default {
    Foo: { bar: () => {} },
    Bar: { foo: () => {} }
};
```

Still throws the same `Cannot read property __ of undefined`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Babel, it's because the `export default` statement is roughly translated to:

```
var foo = {};
exports["default"] = foo;
```

And `import MyObject from './my-object'` is translated to: `var MyObject = require('./my-object').default;`. Which is why your second example works.

However, when you're doing `import { Foo, Bar } from './my-object'`, it is translated to `var { Foo, Bar } = require('./my-object');`

[See this question for extra details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default)

---

In your case, I recommend just using the normal export statement. For example:

```
export class Foo {
  myMethod() {}
};

export const Bar = { a: '1' };
```

Then you can do `import { Foo, Bar } from './my-object';`.

Comment: Great answer, great examples and very concise!

Answer (score -1):

I think You just miss the basic concept.

In this case You are exporting a single object not multiple classes that is why your import is not working as you are thinking.

The syntax works when we have a file say **sample.js** with

```
export var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    return A;
}());

export var B = (function () {
    function B() {
    }
    return B;
}());

export var C = (function () {
    function C() {
    }
    return C;
}());
```

And if you are importing in other file with the following manner :

**import { A, B, C } from './sample';**

I have not tried this but I think It is working like this.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to `import { Foo, Bar} from './my-object'`, you need to explicitly export the Foo and Bar. e.g.

```
export const Foo = { bar() {} };
export const Bar = { foo() {} };
```