# How to use ES6 exports to extend a Backbone Base View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have create a Base Backbone View (BaseView.js) using ES6 `export default View.extend({})` and would like to use ES6 to then extend this view but having trouble doing this `export default BaseView.extend({})` but I get ExtendedView is not a constuctor?

**JS**

```
// BaseView.js
export default View.extend({});
// ExtendedView.js
export default BaseView.extend({});
// Uncaught TypeError: ExtendedView is not a constructor
```

Comment: "*`export default from BaseView.extend({})`*" is a syntax error. You need to put a string literal in the `from` part.

Comment: Where exactly do you get that "is not a constructor" error? What is `ExtendedView`?

Comment: The only way I can get this to work is by using module.exports = BaseView.extend({});

Comment: Try `new ExtendedView.default()`, you might be experiencing the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default

Answer (score 0):

I am working with backbone and ES6 using "module.exports" instead of "export".

```
module.exports = class YourView extends Backbone.View {}
```

I hope it helps.