# JavaScript module not defined with BabelLoader

Tags: javascript, import, export, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm trying to import a package that I've written into another package that I've written.

Pre-Babel Loader

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        // Load flags on import here
        console.log("TESTING CONSTRUCTOR");
    }

    log(message) {
        console.log("TESTING LOG");
    }
}

export default new TestClass();
```

Post Babel Loader

```
var TestClass = function () {
    function TestClass() {
        _classCallCheck(this, TestClass);

        // Load flags on import here
        console.log("TESTING CONSTRUCTOR");
    }

    _createClass(TestClass, [{
        key: "log",
        value: function log(message) {
            console.log("TESTING LOG");
        }
    }]);

    return TestClass;
}();

exports.default = new TestClass();
```

The import itself is simply a `import TestClass from 'testclass-js'`. However, every single time I'm trying to load it I get a "Darklaunch is not defined" error, and can't call any of the methods of the class.

I'm wondering what I've done wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to import the ES5/commonjs version, you'll need to import 'yourmodule'.default; This change came in around babel 6

[Babel 6 changes how it exports default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default)

Read more on the original issue: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2212

If your package contains both an es5 and es6+ version, you can point to the es6 version in the `module` key in `package.json` and webpack/rollup will pick that up and bundle it instead of the commonjs version

Comment: I've tried require but it seems to be undefined. I'd have to load require.js into my package I presume. I'll dig into the original issue and see what I find, thanks.

Comment: Seeing that it says `exports.default`, you can assume that exports is an object that would either have a key for each named export or just default.

const yourThing = require('your-module').default

Would work, but annoying to not use imports. Does that at least work as a start?

Comment: require is undefined since I'm using this in the browser. Doesn't work just straight up.

Comment: Ah, are you not using a bundler? like sourcetype="module" and just importing natively? If so you may need your modules to be using the ES6 exports too, I've never tried using babelified modules straight in browser

Comment: It's an odd setup. I'm doing React SSR with modules inside it, bundled by webpack.