# facing error while implementing nodejs es 6

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have creates a folder named `node_esm` and run commands on terminal `npm init -y`. create a `package.json`. then install two packages `ordinal`and `date-names` by running commands `npm install ordinal` and `npm install date-names`which created a folder named `node_modules`. after that created a file name `index.mjs` and execute it through terminal by using `--experimantal-modules` flag and facing the an error.

`index.mjs` file is :

```
  import ordinal from "ordinal";
  import {days, months} from "date-names";

  console.log(ordinal);
  console.log(months);
```

in `ordinal` folder there is two js files `index.js` and `indicator.js`

`index.js` file is:
var indicator = require('./indicator')

```
  function ordinal (i) {
    if (typeof i !== 'number') throw new TypeError('Expected Number, got ' +(typeof i) + ' ' + i)
    return i + indicator(i) 
  }

  ordinal.indicator = indicator
  module.exports = ordinal
```

`indicator.js` file is:

```
  module.exports = function indicator (i) {
   var cent = i % 100
   if (cent >= 10 && cent <= 20) return 'th'
   var dec = i % 10
   if (dec === 1) return 'st'
   if (dec === 2) return 'nd'
   if (dec === 3) return 'rd'
   return 'th'
   }
```

in `date-names` folder  `index.js` file is:

```
   "use strict";
   module.exports = require('./en');
```

and `en.js` file is:

```
 "use strict";

 module.exports = {
 __locale: "en",
 days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
 abbreviated_days: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
 months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
 abbreviated_months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
 am: 'AM',
 pm: 'PM'
 };
```

and the error is:

```
   (node:8402) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
   file:///home/amarjeet/eloquentjs/ch-10%20modules_1/format-date.mjs:4
   import {days, months} from "date-names";
    ^^^^
   SyntaxError: The requested module 'date-names' does not provide an export named 'days'
   at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:80:21)
```

tell me what`s wrong i am doing.
i am using node version 10.13.0

Comment: I think you should use `export` instead `module.exports` on en.js. (or better, put it directly on date-names script)

Comment: What you are exporting from `en.js` is an object with properties titled `days` and `months`. import the object and access its attributes, like `import dateNames from "date-names";` and then `let days = dateNames.days` or whatever

Comment: @LucasCosta i have used that. thats not working.

Comment: thank you @Katie.Sun. but by doing this `import {days, months} from "date-names";` what wrong in that way. that is also importing object with keys `days` and `months`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import + destructuring using CommonJS export was removed because of confusion between valid and invalid Es6 syntax.

You can check more about these [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/194#issuecomment-168579479) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default/33506169#33506169)

In the meantime, what you can do is (as the link suggests)

```
import data from './Export.js';
const {key} = data;
```

*[feel free to edit this answer for more accurate information]